# React-Native App simulator on webpage

Tags: react-native, simulator

Is it possible to run react-native app on webpage for demo purpose?

Let say you have an App, and would like to show it on your website in simulator,  without installing it on device or using EXPO.

something like appetize.io. But as far as I can see they support only native app, not React based app. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you have connected the same ip network connection in your system and mobile so you can use with

```
adb tcpip

adb tcpip 4455
```

adb connect {mobile ip}:4455

Install and run app in your mobile.
(No need to expo, USB connection .. )

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear what I need, so let me explain again - So, I have app which run in my phone. Then I have a my website. What I want is when user comes to my website, he can run that app in simulator showing on my website. Other word in a website I want to run simulator, which run a mobile app.  Something like here https://appetize.io/